# How do I transfer my NoScript data to a new computer?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, noscript

I use the Firefox add-on [NoScript](http://noscript.net) and would like to transfer it's data to another Firefox installation so that I don't lose all the training I have put into it.  I don't want to copy my entire profile over because something is corrupt and certain add-ons aren't behaving properly.

How do I transfer NoScript data only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go to options in NoScript and on the bottom there are buttons for export and import.

[image]

Comment: No problem, it happens.